# I want to delete the record type which is default to the some profiles

Tags: administration, profile, record-type

Record Type
*Record Type Label

Sales Order
*Record Type Name

Sales_Order

Namespace Prefix
Description 
Active

- > This record type Sales Order cannot be deactivated because the
  >   following profiles use this record type as default.
- This record type Sales Order cannot be deactivated because it is used by the following
  Objects.

> Profiles- System Administrator, Standard User, CC_Customer Community
>   Plus Login Admin CC_Customer Community Plus Login User
>   CC_Marketing_Profile CC_Sales_Profile Chatter External User Chatter
>   Free User Chatter Moderator User Customer Community Plus Login User
>   Customer Community Plus User Deployment Manager Profile Read Only
>   Solution Manager Marketing User Contract Manager Pardot Sync User
>   Profile Objects CC_PO_Update Test_Utility
>   CC_CreateSalesOrderController_Test

Answer (score 4):

Certain Profiles like the Chatter Free User can be assigned Record Types which cannot be removed by clicking an edit link in the Record Type Section of the Profile. This prevents Record Types from being deleted. In order to remove the record type from the Profile a URL 'Hack' must be performed.

Please refer the link for url hack.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2pXAAQ

***Added below the content from the above link to ensure completenedd of the answer:***

---

Certain Profiles like the Chatter Free User can be assigned Record Types which cannot be removed by clicking an edit link in the Record Type Section of the Profile. This prevents Record Types from being deleted. In order to remove the record type from the Profile a URL 'Hack' must be performed.

First, the Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface checkbox in the User Interface must be deselected:

Setup> Customize> User Interface> Setup Section> Deselect  Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface> Save

Proceed with the following Steps:

1)Please follow this click path:

Setup> Manage Users> Profiles> System Administrator> Navigate to Record Types> Click the Edit Link on the Object in question's Section

At this Point you will be at the Edit Record Type Settings Page for the Object.

2)Copy the URL from the adress bar on your browser and paste it into note pad:

https://naX.salesforce.com/setup/ui/profilerecordtypeedit.jsp?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&tid=Opportunity&pn=System+Administrator&retURL=/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

3)Now follow this click path

Setup> Manage Users> Profiles> Chatter Free User

4)Copy the 15 digit Salesforce Id from the URL in the Adress bar of your Browser:

yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

5)You are now going to replace the id in the Edit Record Type Settings Opportunity Page ( the first id number right after the "jsp?id=" in the URL ) with the Id from the Chatter Free User.

This:
https://naX.salesforce.com/setup/ui/profilerecordtypeedit.jsp?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&tid=Opportunity&pn=System+Administrator&retURL=/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Should now look like this:
https://na5.salesforce.com/setup/ui/profilerecordtypeedit.jsp?id=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&tid=Opportunity&pn=System+Administrator&retURL=/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx was replaced with yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

6)Now take the modified Url and place it in the Adress bar of your browser and hit enter.

*************This will seem to have taken you to the System Administrator's edit page but you are in the right place.******************

7)You will now be able to remove the value by highlighting it and selecting remove. Switch the Default record type to whatever you like and hit save.

All you need to do now is repeat this for any other Profiles in which it is necessary, then Deactivate and Delete the Record Type.

Answer (score 3):

So I am sitting here asking myself, hmmmm..... I cannot delete the recordtype because they are the default recordtype for some profiles.....

What should I do......

**BINGO** - Make a different recordtype the default for those profiles!

If you cannot edit the profile directly you will need to URL hack to get the profile ID in the URL to access it but I believe most of your profiles are not in that category

Comment: Just a thought - to rename the same record type & reuse the same, instead of creating another default record type for those profiles?

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar sure unless that is not what you are trying to do